# i386 disassembly using edx register when it is undefined

Tags: assembly, undefined, disassembly, i386, edx

Below is the disassembly of the beginning of a function. The first mention of the edx register is "sarl $0x3, %edx", which shifts the exiting value. As I understand it, the value of the edx register is undefined when entering a function. Can anyone explain what is going on here? Thanks.

```
00007672    pushl   %ebp
00007673    movl    %esp, %ebp
00007675    pushl   %edi
00007676    pushl   %esi
00007677    pushl   %ebx
00007678    calll   0x767d
0000767d    popl    %ebx
0000767e    subl    $0x9c, %esp
00007684    movl    0x14(%ebp), %edi
00007687    movl    0x10(%ebp), %esi
0000768a    calll   __ZN9Node11GetInstanceEv
0000768f    movl    $0x66666667, %ecx
00007694    movl    %eax, -0x8c(%ebp)
0000769a    movl    %esi, %eax
0000769c    imull   %ecx
0000769e    movl    -0x8c(%ebp), %eax
000076a4    sarl    $0x1f, %esi
000076a7    sarl    $0x3, %edx
000076aa    subl    %esi, %edx
000076ac    cvtsi2ssl   %edx, %xmm0
000076b0    leal    -0x2c(%ebp), %esi
```

Comment: Check the documentation for `imul`.

Comment: `edx` is an implicit (destination) operand of `imul`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful replies. Yes, you are right, imul with one argument sets edx to the result.

Comment: related: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41183935/why-does-gcc-use-multiplication-by-a-strange-number-in-implementing-integer-divi).  Looks like signed 32-bit division by a constant.